# Null Pointer Exception for Array List during Run Time but not in the debug mode

Tags: android, for-loop, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have an array list in my class and am getting the value for it as,

```
ArrayList<VenueIcons>  venueArrays = TourDescription.currentTour.getVenues();
```

I am using this array in my for loop

```
for (VenueIcons objVenues : venueArrays)     {



}
```

The problem is, this works fine when I am in the debug mode, but when I try to run it it throws null pointer exception for the same array.

When I debug it, I get all the values for venueArrays without any problem.

Trying to find what went wrong

Comment: It's clear that the TourDescription.currentTour.getVenues() gives you null, you should investigate why this happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give some delay time for getting response for your http call.It should work.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you are dealing with a time based operation. Most probably getVenues() method needs some time in order to fill up the array. So when you are in debug mode it has enough time to do that. In other case it just returns null. You may try to insert a 'sleep' before calling getVenues(). Then observe what is actually happening in getVenues() method.

Hope this helps.